# ConTeXt doesn't generate any pdf output

Tags: pdf, context

I'm using TeXlive 2020. I've organized my project files as:

```
sb-mathematics
    c_chapter-01.tex
    c_chapter-02.tex
    prd_mathematics.tex
env_studentbook.tex
project_studentbook.tex
```

Compiling the *project_studentbook.tex* file doesn't generate any pdf file. Other files generated are:

```
project_studentbook.log
project_studentbook.tuc
```

What am I missing?

#### project_studentbook.tex

```
\startproject project_studentbook
\environment env_studentbook

\product prd_mathematics

\stopproject
```

#### env_studentbook.tex

```
\startenvironment env_studentbook
\project project_studentbook

\usepath[{sb-mathematics}]

\stopenvironment
```

#### prd_mathematics.tex

```
\startproduct prd_mathematics
\project project_studentbook
\environment env_studentbook

\component c_chapter-01
\component c_chapter-02

\stopproduct
```

#### c_chapter-01.tex

```
\startcomponent c_chapter-01
\product prd_mathematics

\chapter{A chapter}

\stopcomponent
```

#### c_chapter-02.tex

```
\startcomponent c_chapter-01
\product prd_mathematics

\chapter{Another chapter}

\stopcomponent
```

Comment: You are supposed to compile the products and components, not the project. This is confusing, I know, just think of projects as global setups for a magazine or book series and the individual issues or books as the compilable products. Cf. https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Project_structure

Comment: Oh! I was under the impression that compiling the project would generate pdfs for different products. I just realized, compiling products/components make sense because you wouldn't want multiple pdfs to be generated every time you compile a project. @DG'